# Android Updating Security Provider

Tags: android, security, xamarin, xamarin.android, google-play-services

I'm working on Xamarin.Native and trying to implement a security patch for Xamarin.Android project.

According to this [doc](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-gms-provider#java) from Google, you invoke `ProviderInstaller.InstallIfNeeded()` or the async version of it.

This method throws 2 types of exceptions, [GooglePlayServicesRepairableException](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesRepairableException) and [GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException).

According to the documentation above, RepairableException is thrown when Play services is not installed, out of date or disabled.

I'm trying to test all those scenarios on my physical device and emulator, but only able to test when it's disabled.

When Google play services is out of date(both device and emulator), the exception does not get thrown and `InstallIfNeeded` returns normally. I have a device with Google play services `17.7.86`, at the time of writing this the latest version is `20.03.13`.

When Google play services is not installed(emulator), I get `GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException` when I was expecting to get a repairable exception and pop up a dialog to let the user to install.

How do you test when Google play services is out of date or not installed so that the corresponding exception would get thrown?

Answer (score 0):

The **GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException** will contain an **ErrorCode** . You could handle it with different logic .

```
try
{

}
catch(GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException ex)
{ 
  int errorcode = ex.ErrorCode;
}
```

For more details about the error code you could check https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/ConnectionResult.html#constants_1

Comment: My question was how to repro these exceptions. I am only able to get `GooglePlayServicesRepairableException` when play services is disabled on the device. When it's out of date or not installed I'm not getting that exception.

Comment: You test it on real device .

Comment: I did test on my physical device as well and I still wasn't able to get that exception when play services is out of date.

Comment: Could you share a sample which contains the issue so that I can test it on my side .